# Ignoring unnecessary characters while reading from file in C

Tags: c, file, struct

I have a programming assignment that gives a data file “candidatesdata.txt”
You are supposed to read information in and decipher what is the name, gender, height, and weight. The only problem is that there are quotations around the name and commas in between each data record. The file goes as follows:

```
Name,Gender,Height,Weight
"Tanner, Mark C.”,M,71.8,180.25
"Jinglehiemmerschmitt, John J.”,M,70.75,185.3
"Parker, Sarah J.",F,65.25,120.3
```

..cont.

How do I read the data records and ignore the quotations and the commas?
This is what I have so far, it deletes some commas and quotations but also in the process it deletes the names.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct candidateinfo
{
    char name[50];
    char gender;
    double height;
    double weight;
}candidate;


    int main()
{
    int count =0;
    FILE *candidate_data;


    // Open file
    candidate_data = fopen("/Users/moisestrevino/Documents/CS 1324/Assignment #5/Assignment #5/candidatedata.txt","r");

    fscanf(candidate_data, "%*[^\n]");
    fgetc(candidate_data);

    // Get rid of unecessary letters

      while (count<40)
      {
          count++;

         fscanf(candidate_data,"\"%[^\"],%c,%lf,%lf\n", candidate.name, &candidate.gender, &candidate.height, &candidate.weight);

          printf("%s %c %lf %lf\n",candidate.name, candidate.gender, candidate.height, candidate.weight);
      }

    fclose(candidate_data);
    return 0;

 }
```

Output:

```
     Tanner, Mark C.  0.000000 0.000000
,M,71.8,180.25
  0.000000 0.000000
Jinglehiemmerschmitt, John J.  0.000000 0.000000
,M,70.75,185.3
  0.000000 0.000000
Parker, Sarah J.  0.000000 0.000000
,F,65.25,120.3
  0.000000 0.000000
Meeks, Kalvin R.  0.000000 0.000000
,M,57.25,210.2


cont...
```

Comment: you ___must___ read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2173917) first.

Comment: And also please indent your code

Comment: Should I use EOF instead?

Comment: use `fgetc()` instead of `fscanf()` for that.

Comment: Some of your quote characters are non-ASCII typographic quote marks - did you paste this from a word document? Also, the reason for the quotes is that there are commas inside the name field.

Comment: Leave the commas, just detect them in your fscanf formats they are field delimiters. As for the quotes it's easier to read them in as part of the name, which you then tweak the string in your program. Skip the first line using format "%[^\n]\n". Read a line with scanf( " %s., %lf , %lf., %lf \n",candidate.name, &candidate.age,&candidate.height,&candidate.weight);

Comment: @rhubarbdog `"%s"` will not scan in `"Tanner, Mark C."` due to its spaces and only scan in `"Tanner,"`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains lots of problems. There are too many to mention , so here is the fix:

If the file contains data in the form:

```
Name,Gender,Height,Weight
```

and then,

```
"Tanner, Mark C.",M,71.8,180.25
"Jinglehiemmerschmitt, John J.",M,70.75,185.3
"Parker, Sarah J.",F,65.25,120.3
```

then the below fix will work out.

After the `fopen`, you can use

```
fscanf(candidate_data, "%*[^\n]");
fgetc(candidate_data);
```

The first line scans and discards everything until a newline character. The second line consumes the newline character. After this, use

```
fscanf(candidate_data, " \"%[^\"]\",%c,%lf,%lf", name, gender, height, weight);
```

Assuming you have already declared a `char` array of considerable size named `name`, a `char` of name `gender` and two `double`s of names `height` and `weight`, here is the breakdown of the above `fscanf`:

- (space) scans and discards all whitespace characters until the first non-whitespace character.
- `\"` scans the `"` from the file and discards it.
- `%[^\"]` scans everything until a `"` and stores it in `name`.
- `\"` scans the `"` from the file and discards it.
- `,` scans and discards a comma.
- `%c` scans a character and stores it in `gender`.
- `,` scans and discards a comma.
- `%lf` scans a `double` and stores it in `height`.
- `,` scans and discards a comma.
- `%lf` scans a `double` and stores it in `weight`.

Now you can print each value. Read more data by putting the above `fscanf` in a loop.

But how do you know when the data has ended? Check the return value of `fscanf`. `fscanf` returns the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.

In your case, `fscanf` will return 4 if all data was successfully scanned. So, just read on data until `fscanf` does not return 4.

---

As suggested by @chux, You can prevent buffer overflows by using

```
fscanf(candidate_data, " \"%49[^\"]\",%c,%lf,%lf", name, gender, height, weight);
```

The 49 tells `scanf` to scan a maximum of 49 characters for `name`(+1 for the NUL-terminator)

Comment: `" \"%[^\"]",%c,%lf,%lf"` --> `" \"%[^\"]\",%c,%lf,%lf"`  (add slash)  Further Suggestion `" \"%49[^\"]\", %c ,%lf ,%lf"`  (add spaces, width)

Comment: @chux , Thanks. Missed the slash. As per the OP's format of the text file, the spaces aren't required. Added the other suggestion.

Comment: Recommend adding @Random832 comment about input file using various quote makes `"Tanner, Mark C.”`  `"` vs. `”`.

Comment: @chux , BTW, How do I scan `”` and print it in the console? `fscanf` doesn't seem to work as expected and printing `”` also prints weird things in the console.

Comment: `”` (and this is not `"`) is a non-ASCII character.  To read this in from the console and to print out correctly is system specific - unable to provide general solution.  Printing usually involves using `wprintf()` and `wchar_t`.

Answer (score 0):

If each line contains all fields, you can use str(r)chr+atof instead, e.g.

```
char line[100];
while( fgets(line,100,candidate_data) )
{
  char *p = strrchr(line,',');
  weight = atof(p+1); *p=0;
  p = strrchr(line,',');
  height = atof(p+1);
  gender = *--p;
  *strrchr(line,'"')=0;
  strcpy( name, strchr(line,'"')+1 );
}
```